# how to find the path for default pdf reader in ubuntu10.10?

Tags: java, linux, pdf, ubuntu

i want to give path of document viewer ,which is a default pdf reader with ubunutu10.10 in my java app...

i tried to find the path of app using

**$ which documentviewer**

on command prompt..but got no result...

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I suppose you do that to latter open a pdf document with it, no ? if so, please don't try to build the command line, but rather *please* rely upon Desktop class (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then binary is called `evince`, as that's the product name. "Document viewer" is just the generic term.

Answer (score 3):

It's called `evince`:

```
$ which evince
/usr/bin/evince
```